# Lingo game adding input to the gridlayout

Tags: java

So for my school project I have to make the game Lingo, it's a 5x5 wordgame.

I made a very basic layout as you can see, I'm using a gridlayout and the squares are all labels, not Jlabels. Now my problem is, how can I add user input to the labels? One letter only. I already wrote a code to control the input, but I'm not sure how to code the input itself.

Comment: "_as you can see, I'm using ..._" No we can't see. There are no screenshots or code. "_I already wrote a code to control the input_" If we are to help you fix/add to your code we need to see it. Can you post it here as an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21557235/edit) to your question?

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img837/6817/6lyq.png - here is a picture of the lay-out, its a gridlayout of labels